# Hiding a form, switch to a second form, close second form and unhide first form

Tags: c#, winforms

I've looked at all the suggested answers and nothing seems to fit what I'm looking for. I want to call a second form from my main form, hide my main form while the second form is active, and then unhide the main form when the second form closes.  Basically I want to "toggle" between the two forms.

So far I have:

In my main form:

```
private void countClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide(); 
    subForm myNewForm = new subForm();
    myNewForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

and in my second form I have:

```
private void totalClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

How do I get the main form to show?

Answer (score 2):

[ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) opens your secondary Form as Modal Dialog, meaning that the MainForm's code execution will stop at that point and your secondary Form will have the focus. so all that you need to do is put a `this.Show` after your ShowDialog call.

From above link:

> You can use this method to display a modal dialog box in your application. When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed.

```
private void countClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide(); 
    subForm myNewForm = new subForm();
    myNewForm.ShowDialog();
    this.Show();
}
```

Comment: I would only add one caveat... if the current form is also modal dialog and you hide it... doesn't that kill the modality?  If so, I would just suggest preserving the top or left position of the window, set it to something like -2000, then set it back when the other form closes.

Comment: @DRapp Since he mentioned that he is calling from his MainForm most likely in my mind that is going to be his program's main form. So the scenario you are describing is highly unlikely. Also running a quick test generating another Modal Dialog box from the secondary form did not break the Modality.

Comment: If a modal dialog is not what you want you can always call myNewForm.Show(this) and then have a reference to the form as Parent where you can call show/hide

Comment: @Mataniko If he is wanting to use Show instead of ShowDialog, I personally would use Edper's answer, though what you describe works also.

Comment: Yep, another good option, didn't think it would work as a comment so decided to just add on to yours :)

Comment: @MarkHall Thanks for the quick response, your answer did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say in `Form1` you click a Button to show `Form2`

```
 Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
 frm2.Activated += new EventHandler(frm2_Activated); // Handler when the form is activated
 frm2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(frm2_FormClosed); // Hander when the form is closed
 frm2.Show();
```

Now, this one is when the `Form2` is shown or is `Activated` you hide the calling form, in this case the `Form1`

```
    private void frm2_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide(); // Hides Form1 but it is till in Memory
    }
```

Then when `Form2` is `Closed` it will `Unhide` `Form1`.

```
   private void frm2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Show(); // Unhide Form1
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to do correctly.  The issue is that you **must** avoid having no window at all that can get the focus.  The Windows window manager will be forced to find another window to give the focus to.  That will be a window of another application.  Your window will disappear behind it.

That's already the case in your existing code snippet, you are hiding your main window before showing the dialog.  That *usually* turns out okay, except when the dialog is slow to create.  It will definitely happen when the dialog is closed.

So what you need to do is hide your window *after* you display the dialog and show it again *before* the dialog closes.  That requires tricks.  They look like this:

```
private void countClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.Hide()));
    using (var dlg = new subForm()) {
        dlg.FormClosing += (s, fcea) => { if (!fcea.Cancel) this.Show(); };
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            // etc...
        }
    }
}
```

The BeginInvoke() call is a trick to get code to run after the ShowDialog() method runs.  Thus ensuring your window is hidden after the dialog window is shown.  The FormClosing event of the dialog is used to get the window to be visible again just before the dialog closes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in the same namespace, you have the context, using `mainform` or the name you gave the "main form", try:

```
mainform.show();
```

Comment: What is `mainform`? Where is it defined? Where should this be inserted? Please provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find some way to pass a reference to the main form to the second form click event handler.

You can do this either by setting the form as a member variable of the second form class or pass it via the event arguments.