# hide main form, start new form, switch between the two without closing second form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I've got two forms, with subForm being called/created by a buttonClick in Form1.  Right now I can initiate subForm, hide Form1, and then unhide Form1 when subForm is closed.  What I'd like to be able to do is:

1. If user clicks changeform button, check to see if subForm is active but hidden
2. If no, then initiate subForm, else hide Form1, unhide subForm and pass control to it
3. If user clicks subForm's changeform button, hide subForm, unhide Form1 and pass control to it
4. If user clicks the "X" in the upper right corner of the form, then close the application, regardless of which form is active.  (Right now, selecting the "X" closes the subForm and opens/unhides Form1.)

I can find solutions that do part of the requirements (and maybe all, I'm just too noob to know).  To repeat from my previous question here, the code I have so far is:

Form1

```
    private void countClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide(); 
        subForm myNewForm = new subForm();
        myNewForm.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
        countSelect.Checked = false;
    }
```

and subForm

```
    private void totalClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

This works, but it's not really elegant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hiding a form, switch to a second form, close second form and unhide first form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287361/hiding-a-form-switch-to-a-second-form-close-second-form-and-unhide-first-form)

Comment: @musefan That was my original question, which was answered by the code snippets shown here.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this is to roll your own `ApplicationContext`. This allows you full control over the application lifetime without having it being tied to a specific Window. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157901.aspx for more information.

Here's an example:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MyApplicationContext());
    }
}

public class MyApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
{
    public MyApplicationContext()
    {
        ShowForm1();
    }

    public void ShowForm1()
    {
        if (_form2 != null)
            _form2.Hide();
        if (_form1 == null)
        {
            _form1 = new Form1(this);
            _form1.FormClosed += OnFormClosed;
        }
        _form1.Show();
        MainForm = _form1;
    }

    public void ShowForm2()
    {
        if (_form1 != null)
            _form1.Hide();
        if (_form2 == null)
        {
            _form2 = new Form2(this);
            _form2.FormClosed += OnFormClosed;
        }
        _form2.Show();
        MainForm = _form2;
    }

    private void OnFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_form1 != null)
        {
            _form1.Dispose();
            _form1 = null;
        }
        if (_form2 != null)
        {
            _form2.Dispose();
            _form2 = null;
        }
        ExitThread();
    }

    private Form1 _form1;
    private Form2 _form2;
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1(MyApplicationContext context)
        : this()
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_context != null)
            _context.ShowForm2();
    }

    private readonly MyApplicationContext _context;
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2(MyApplicationContext context)
        : this()
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_context != null)
            _context.ShowForm1();
    }

    private readonly MyApplicationContext _context;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So we'll start out by going to the child form and creating a new event that can be used to notify the parent when it wants to change forms:

```
public event Action ChangeForm;
```

Then we fire the event and hide the child form when it wants to change forms:

```
private void ChangeForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
    if (ChangeForm != null)
        ChangeForm();
}
```

The parent form needs an instance of the child form as an instance field:

private subForm child = new subForm();

And it needs to initialize it in it's constructor, both adding handlers to the ChangeForm event to show the parent, and to the closed event to close itself:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    child.ChangeForm += () => Show();
    child.FormClosed += (s, args) => Close();
}
```

Then all that's left is for the parent form to hide itself and show the child when it wants to change forms:

```
private void ChangeForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
    child.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Actually, thanks to all who answered. This is the route I took and all is working fine. Thanks again.

Comment: `form2.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();` May I know how does this statement work? what exactly `(s,args)` is? What is the use of lambda operator (=>) ?

Comment: @YashSaraiya Sounds like you already know that it's a lambda, so you can simply search for whatever it is that you'd like to know about it.

Comment: @Servy I got the lambda thing sorted, but what about `(s, args)` ? Can you please explain?

Comment: @YashSaraiya Those are the arguments for the lambda.

Comment: Can I replace it with some other letters or this is the standard way of writing?

Comment: @YashSaraiya Try it and find out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply setting them to foreground, topmost, and so on ?
And setting them back vice versa ?

---added as comment as proposed

Comment: He's *not* passing a reference of the parent form to the child form, so why are you telling him not to do it?

Comment: this.MainFormRef_Field = MainFormRef;

what is this ?

Comment: That's some other user's answer, not the OP.  Perhaps you should comment on that answer if you would like to respond to it.

Answer (score -1):

**To access `MainForm` from`subForm`**:

Create a constructor in your `subForm` and a field:

```
MainForm MainFormRef_Field;
subForm(MainForm MainFormRef)
{
    this.MainFormRef_Field = MainFormRef;
}
```

Now you can access your `MainForm` using this reference. Like this:

```
MainFormRef_Field.Show();
MainFormRef_Field.Hide(); //or how ever you want to handle it
```

**To access `subForm` from`MainForm`**:

To handle your `subForm` use the object you created for it. Here:

```
subForm myNewForm = new subForm();
```

**To close whole application if any of the form closes:**

Set a `Form_Closing` event for both forms:

```
private void MainForm_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}

private void subForm_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

**Note:**

I am not writing the whole code for all of your cases. Set the variables, check the conditions. Its all up to you that how code it. All the main points you needed I've provided you the solution of them.

Comment: I didn't do it. Don't know why it's there.

Comment: Wasn't me either, but i placed a part of my answer here ( because it refers more to Your answer than to the OP's question:

Accessing parent-form from child form is bad style and cross reference .
Better way is to make the child form as popup and react to dialog result, or something like that.

Or react to other events on parent form.
But not passing parent reference to child.